# How to install whm,cPanel in my laptop?

Tags: linux, centos, server, cpanel

I want to install whm & cpanel in my laptop. I install centOs 6.4 using oracle virtualBox as per instruction/iso in http://www.comunidadhosting.com/t/tutorial-de-como-instalar-cpanel-en-localhost.18879/.

After install it i check IP and it show me 10.0.2.15 . but my main problem is I am not able ping to guest machine from my host. When I ping from my guest to host machine then it's working fine , and host get internet access also.

I use NAT in networking.
Can any body tell me what is the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: i suggest you use bridged connection and use same network range on your centos also: like if you use : 192.168.1.1 on main PC TAP than use 192.168.1.2 on centos network setting

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have a bridged connection OR a NAT connection with the outside host network. Both should have the same network connection and IP may be same/different.

And, if you have done this, then you need to disable the firewall on the guest-machine side so that your host machine could connect to the VM.

Your ping may then be failing because of getting blocked by the VM's firewall.

Comment: Hi @asad thanks for answer , I already mention that I use NAT setting in virtualBox.
I am unable to ping from centOs (Guest) to Win 8.1(Host) machine, but I able to ping opposite.

Comment: @SKG-Would you please describe at which step are you stuck? Actually, I reversed the answer. I carefully looked your question, you need to ping your guest from your host. Soo, turn off the firewall of VM. Check if `firewalld` is creating trouble for you in CentOS(VM).

Comment: As per instruction I stop firewall in vm but it didn't work. Now I forward the port to vm and it's working now